# Do a groupby follow by a join on Bigquery

Tags: nosql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables as shown below:

[image]

How can I group by ID and join these two tables to form a final this table

[image]

Where each ID in table 2 has the values A,B,C,D and E from Table 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

[image]

with result

[image]

Comment: I love your handwriting <3